# discord.py - How do I add a command to a parent-command

Tags: python-3.x, command, discord.py

I would like to assign commands as a paramter to another command.

I tried something like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def the_parrent():
    pass

@bot.command(parent=the_parrent)
async def child1(ctx):
    await ctx.send("This is child 1")

@bot.command(parent=the_parrent)
async def child2(ctx):
    await ctx.send("And this is child 2")
```

Now when I write
**!the_parrent**
nothing happens as expected, but if I write
**!the_parrent child1**
or
**!the_parrent child2**
nothing happens too.

But if I only write **!child1** or **!child2**, the corresponding message is sent by the bot.

The inbuilt **!help** command also shows that *child1* and *child2* aren't assigned to *the_parrent* too:

```
​No Category:
 child1      
 child2      
 help        Shows this message
 the_parrent 
 
Type !help command for more info on a command.
You can also type !help category for more info on a category.
```

So, my question is am I understanding the parent-parameter wrong? And if not, how do I add a command to another command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `parent` parameter! The `parents` attribute is just an `attribute` that returns all of the parents that that command is assigned to. These things are called `command groups` instead of `parents`, and you should create your "parent command" like this:

```
@bot.group()
async def parent_command(ctx):
    pass
```

by giving it the `bot.group()` decorator.

Afterwards, you can assign subcommands to it by using `@parent_command.command()` instead of `@bot_command`.

```
@parent_command.command()
async def subcommand(ctx):
    await ctx.send("This is child 1.")
```

You can choose if you always want your parent command to be called, or only when no subcommand is found by adding the `ìnvoke_without_command=True` kwarg to it.

```
@bot.group(invoke_without_command=True)
async def parent_command(ctx):
    pass
```

That way, `!parent_command` and `!parent_command somethingsomething` will trigger the parent command, and `!parent_command subcommand` will trigger the subcommand.

More info & optional kwargs can be found in the [commands.group docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=group#discord.ext.commands.Group).